# How can I disable Quick Find hotkey in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

Firefox's Quick Find, activated with ‘/’, is a feature that I really don't use and the key conflicts with access keys in certain web sites (namely Pinboard and ScalaDoc). How can I disable this feature or at least its access key?

I have tried Customizable Shortcuts, but it does not seem to let me change this shortcut.

Comment: It's unfortunate that Firefox's plugin architecture doesn't allow sufficient access to create any kind of hotkey rebinding extension.  I fought with this issue a great deal and eventually switched to a different browser because of it.

Comment: Which version of Firefox?

Comment: @iglvzx FF 12.0

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `searchkeys.disable.all` in `about:config` as true.

Comment: No dice - set the setting, restarted Firefox, and the search keys are still present & working :(

Comment: Cheers worked for me!

Comment: There is no such property in FF v60

Answer (score 1):

There is an "unofficial" plugin called SearchHotKeys available here: http://nic-nac-project.de/~kaosmos/index-en.html (it's about 3/4 down the rather large page).  It seems to do the trick (I have FF 12.0 and it worked for me).