# How can I disable Quick Find hotkey in Firefox 59?

Tags: firefox, hotkeys

I have the "search for text when you start typing" option disabled in Firefox Developer Edition, but pressing the / key still opens the quick find pane rather than just passing the keypress to the webpage.

How can I disable this extremely annoying functionality?

(Please note: this is not exactly a duplicate of [How can I disable Quick Find hotkey in Firefox?](https://superuser.com/questions/425301/how-can-i-disable-quick-find-hotkey-in-firefox) as the question is six years old and the solution given is not compatible with modern Firefox versions, even once xpinstall.signatures.required is set to false. I'm assuming that asking anew is better than simply trying to tack on to the end of the old question, but please let me know if not and I'll delete this one.)

Comment: Wish there was a solution to this :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User can now disable the quick find bar again from Firefox 63.

[This reddit thread by a Firefox Engineer](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/8wj629/in_firefox_nightly_you_can_now_disable_the_quick/) in July 2018 has noted this:

> In Firefox Nightly you can now disable the quick find bar (opened by pressing / or ') with accessibility.typeaheadfind.manual set to false in about:config.

The title says it all, leaving no room to explain further.